# Oracle SQL Developer - transpose table leaving multiple rows for the same ID

Tags: sql, oracle, max, min, transpose

I'm working on a report with a following kind of table (values are made-up for the sake of demo):

```
___________________________________________
|__ID__|_Feline_|_Canine_|_Avian__|_Rodent_|
|_1001_|_Snow___|_[null]_|_[null]_|_[null]_|
|_1001_|_[null]_|_Spike__|_[null]_|_[null]_|
|_1001_|_[null]_|_[null]_|_Polly__|_[null]_|
|_1001_|_[null]_|_[null]_|_[null]_|_Jumper_|
|_1001_|_Max____|_[null]_|_[null]_|_[null]_|
```

What I would like to do, is cram the values into a single row (which worked using MAX(CASE) and GROUP BY ID), but also have an additional row for the same ID if there are more occurrences of, in this case, "Feline" values (which doesn't happen if GROUP BY ID is used):

```
___________________________________________
|__ID__|_Feline_|_Canine_|_Avian__|_Rodent_|
|_1001_|_Snow___|_Spike__|_Polly__|_Jumper_|
|_1001_|_Max____|_Spike__|_Polly__|_Jumper_|
```

My best choice is probably to have MAX(CASE) for Feline1 and MIN(CASE) for Feline2 to get both of them into the same row (different columns) instead of two rows (same column), but I wanted to know if there is a way to get the result above.

Much appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like you want a `CROSS JOIN` of some kind.  Possibly subqueried in a `SELECT DISTINCT` of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst there are maximum two non NULL values per column, you could go with

```
SELECT
  ID
  , MIN(Feline) Feline
  , MIN(Canine) Canine
  , MIN(Avian) Avian
  , MIN(Rodent) Rodent
FROM Input
GROUP BY ID
UNION ALL
SELECT
  ID
  , MAX(Feline)
  , MAX(Canine)
  , MAX(Avian)
  , MAX(Rodent)
FROM Input
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID
;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a6c1b/1/0)

Otherwise either one of the following should help - as long as names are not repeated within a column:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  T1.ID
  , T2.Feline
  , T3.Canine
  , T4.Avian
  , T5.Rodent
FROM Input T1, Input T2, Input T3, Input T4, Input T5
WHERE T2.Feline IS NOT NULL
  AND T3.Canine IS NOT NULL
  AND T4.Avian IS NOT NULL
  AND T5.Rodent IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY ID, Feline, Canine, Avian, Rodent
;

SELECT
  T1.ID
  , T2.Feline
  , T3.Canine
  , T4.Avian
  , T5.Rodent
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    T1.ID
  FROM Input T1
) T1, Input T2, Input T3, Input T4, Input T5
WHERE
  T2.Feline IS NOT NULL
  AND T3.Canine IS NOT NULL
  AND T4.Avian IS NOT NULL
  AND T5.Rodent IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY ID, Feline, Canine, Avian, Rodent
;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a6c1b/1/0)

If there are repeats within a column - well, what should the output look like? The very last one will have them, the one before won't.

If I missed a bit, just comment, and I'll try to follow up.